# Override following digits in QSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a property in Q(Double)SpinBox that allows the user to override digits that are right of the curser, just by typing?

For example: If the spinbox shows `12.52` I click between `1` and `2`. Now I type `3.45` to get `13.45`

Comment: typing 1 2 3.45 should intuitively produce ***123.45***

Comment: I meant the 1 in the example to stay there from a previous input.
Or, in this example, type 3 4 after the seperator to get 12.34 - without deleting 52 before.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked it out - even activating Insert mode on keyboard doesn't help.

Apparently, you'll have to subclass QSPinBox and override some QAbstractSpinBox functions - at least, keyPressEvent.

QAbstractSpinBox has a pointer to underlying QLineEdit - which has a cursor position property.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property, you can go with your own implementation like this:

**Header:**

```cpp
#include <QObject>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>

class CustomSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomSpinBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override;

private:
    void updateTextField(const QString &text);
};
```

**Source:**

```cpp
#include "CustomSpinBox.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QLineEdit>

CustomSpinBox::CustomSpinBox(QWidget *parent)
    : QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
{}

void CustomSpinBox::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    auto isInt = false;
    event->text().toInt(&isInt);

    if (isInt)
    {
        updateTextField(event->text());
    }
    else
    {
        QDoubleSpinBox::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}

void CustomSpinBox::updateTextField(const QString &text)
{
    auto lineEdit = this->lineEdit();
    auto cursorPosition = lineEdit->cursorPosition();
    auto lineEditText = lineEdit->text();
    QChar currentChar;

    if (cursorPosition < lineEditText.size())
    {
        currentChar = lineEditText.at(cursorPosition);
        if (currentChar.isPunct())
        {
            lineEdit->cursorForward(false);
        }
    }

    lineEdit->del();
    lineEdit->insert(text);
}
```

But please note that the behaviour can be counter-intuitive. What if the value is `1,23`? With that approach, you cannot enter any value bigger than `9,(9)`. Maybe it is what is expected, maybe it should not jump over the dot/comma unless the value before the punctuation mark has size length bigger than 2 digits (or 3 or any other number).